# output array of class names on to element ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

I have array of class names that I want to attach to an element for example..

```
Tags = [tag1, tag2, tag3] ;
<article ng-class="tag1, tag2, tag3"></article>
```

is there any way I can use a for loop on the ng-class to output this array onto the element..

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-class can take array itself so provided `Tags` is a property of the scope you could do:-

```
 <article ng-class="Tags"></article>
```

[ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

> Expression to eval. The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element.

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.Tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];
});
```

```css
.tag1.tag2.tag3{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <article ng-class="Tags">Article</article>
</div>
```